# How to group by in postgres by using MM-YYYY instead of DD_MM_YYYY?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a query in PgAdmin, where one column named 'joining_date' in output returns a date.

When I use Group By I would like using only `MM_YYY` instead of `DD_MM_YYY` which is output datatype of 'joining_date' so that same employee_type can be grouped together.

```
create table employee(joining_date date, 
employee_type varchar, name character varying);

insert into employee values
('16-11-2022', 'Intern', 'ABBS'),
('11-11-2022', 'senior', 'ABBS'),
('12-11-2022', 'senior', 'ABBS'),
('11-11-2022', 'senior', 'ABBS'),
('12-11-2022', 'Intern', 'ABBS');

select employee_type as emp, 
to_char(joining_date, 'MM_YY') as batch, 
count(employee_type) as num
from employee
GROUP BY employee_type, joining_date;
```

What I obtained is:

| emp | batch | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Intern | 11_22 | 1 |
| senior | 11_22 | 1 |
| Intern | 11_22 | 1 |
| senior | 11_22 | 2 |

What I want to obtain is:

| emp | batch | num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Intern | 11_22 | 2 |
| senior | 11_22 | 3 |

How to proceed?

Comment: select employee_type as emp, to_char(joining_date, 'MM_YY') as batch, count(employee_type) as num from employee GROUP BY employee_type, to_char(joining_date, mm_yy)      does this work ?

Comment: Related https://xkcd.com/1179/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is almost correct.

But you need to use the same formatting in selection and `GROUP BY`, otherwise your grouping has not the intended effect.

So if your selection should be done as `TO_CHAR(joining_date, 'MM_YY')`, this must be used in the `GROUP BY` clause, too.

```
SELECT employee_type AS emp, 
TO_CHAR(joining_date, 'MM_YY') AS batch, 
COUNT(employee_type) AS num 
FROM employee 
GROUP BY employee_type, 
TO_CHAR(joining_date, 'MM_YY');
```

You can replicate here that this will produce the expected result: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GQL8D_sJ)

Comment: You could also try to be lazy and use the numbered columns: GROUP BY 1, 2